# Bank statement in a different currency when applying for visa

Tags: visa

Is it a big deal to apply for a visa with a bank statement in a different currency? I am a Czech student studying in the UK and I will be applying in London for a student visa to South Korea. However, I have my money in a Czech account and I don't want to transfer it to my British account because there would be money transfer charges. Will my bank statement be accepted in a different currency if I translate it (from Czech) and notarize it?

Comment: Do you mean "fines" (money you have to pay for breaking the law)? or "charges" (money you have to pay for the service of converting your money from CZK to GBP).  There may be a problem if you can't use the Koruna in Korea.

Comment: I would say it would be accepted but only the consulate can answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn’t. I actually used my Czech bank statement back home in my country (Ghana) in applying for UK Visa and was granted. Just that, I printed the English version online then convert the currency in it equivalence to British Pounds at www.oanda.com ( official conversion site that UKVI officials mostly used). Added a covering letter explicitly explaining the conversion.